# How to override theme function

Tags: wordpress

I need to override theme function in child theme.
I have  code in themefolder/core/inc

```
function uncode_woocommerce_order_button_html( $button ) {
    $button = str_replace('"button', '"btn btn-default', $button);
    return $button;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', 'uncode_woocommerce_order_button_html', 10, 1 );
```

I need to change this function in childtheme to

```
    $button = str_replace('"button', '" another values', $button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling another function by `woocommerce_order_button_html` filter in your child theme's functions.php with a higher priority.

Your code may become something like this:

```
function update_wc_order_button( $button ) {
    $button = str_replace('"button', '" another values', $button);
    return $button;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', 'update_wc_order_button', 11, 1 ); // 11 is the priority here.
```